# HTML canvas image is fading out after multiple iterations/reusing

Tags: html, canvas, scaling, fading, todataurl

I have a portal which is used for collecting orders from users in hand written format.

In my portal, I am using HTML canvas for getting inputs from user.

Once the user write order and submits it, I will read the drawings from the canvas and saves it into my DB.

```
HTML

    <canvas height="750" width="768" id="userNotes"></canvas>

Javascript

    var canvas = document.getElementById('userNotes');
    var notesDataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

    saveImageDataToDataBase (notesDataURL);
```

Next time when the user comes for a new order, I will draw this image back into the canvas, so that he can make modifications on the same and submit it as fresh order.

```
Javascript
    var canvas = document.getElementById('userNotes');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = imageData;
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

Problem that I am facing is that after multiple iterations, the image starts fading out.

One observation is that fading is more at the bottom part of the image and less on the top side.

Consider the below sample images,

After 10 iterations image became like this,

[image: Image - 1]

Below is a JS FIddle created using sample code, in this after about 25 iterations fading will be visible(issue is visible only in tablet mentioned below).

https://jsfiddle.net/hz8r993v/

Observation:
An observation which I made is the issue is happening only in a specific tablet model, **Samsung SM-P550**, which is unfortunately the one my application is build for.

I am not able to reproduce this issue while using this application in my laptop, PC or another sm-p650 tablet.

Currently Only happening in all tablets of model SM-P550. Even I am confused with this observation.

I also tried disabling ImageSmoothingEnabled properties, but not helping.

Any leads/clues are appreciated.

Comment: Did you scale the canvas by any chance?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the canvas before redrawind the image? maybe context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height) can help.

Comment: @prashant, I am not scaling it. Using it in the same canvas(with the same size).

Comment: @adonike, Yes,  I do clear the canvas.

Comment: The only time a similar thing happened to me was when I used floating point coordinates to draw in the canvas. Any chance that same thing is happening? i solved it by using only integer values.

Comment: @adonike, I am not using floating point coordinates :-(

Comment: There is not enough in your code blocks to reproduce your issue. First I'm suprised that you get anything drawn with the second snippet : you are not waiting for the image has loaded before drawing it, which is calling for troubles, but not the ones you experience. For your problem, I'll make a wild guess and tell that you are probably saving as `image/jpeg`, maybe even with some quality param. Each time you'll redraw this jpeg image, it will be uncompressed, but will keep its jpeg artifacts, which will only grow at each iteration, for finally produce something like what you gave us.

Comment: Does `saveImageDataToDataBase` maintain the PNG data without compacting the image into a lossy format such as JPG?

Answer (score 3):

## JPEG compression quirk & rounding.

Looking at the image you provided suggests to me that you are incorrectly offsetting the image each time you render it. As you have not provided enough code for anyone to make an assessment as to why this is happening leaves us only to guess.

---

### Lossless JPEG!

My first instinct is that you have offset the drawing or scaled it. I create the example below and offset a jpeg url of the rendered text by 0.2 pixels.

The result **no blur** Not a real surprise Jpegs are designed so that they can be copied. The artifacts introduced by the compression actually remove the blur introduced by the offset

#### Draw jpeg image 0.2 pixels down save and repeat.

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "64px Arial";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
ctx.fillText("testing",canvas.width / 2,canvas.height / 2);
ctx.font = "18px Arial";
var count = 0;
var imgURL;
function copy(){
    imgURL = canvas.toDataURL();
}
function paste(x,y){
    var img = new Image;
    img.src = imgURL;
    img.onload = function(){
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(img,x,y);
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fillText("Copy : " + count,canvas.width / 2,count * 20);
    }
}
function iterate(){
    count += 1;
    copy();
    paste(0,0.2);
    if(count < 100){
       setTimeout(iterate,50);
    }
}

iterate();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width = 300 height = 150></canvas>
```

Your image clearly shows a vertical blurring so I set about finding when I can blur the image so that it over comes the Jpeg compression. Offsetting by 0.5 or more does not blur the image just scrolls pixel perfect 100 pixels (note I copy past 100 times move image 0.5 pixels down yet resulting image has moved 100 pixels.  I have marked row 100)

#### Jpeg turns 0.5 pixel steps into 1 pixel steps

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "64px Arial";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
ctx.fillText("testing",canvas.width / 2,canvas.height / 2);
ctx.font = "18px Arial";
var count = 0;
var imgURL;
function copy(){
    imgURL = canvas.toDataURL();
}
function paste(x,y){
    var img = new Image;
    img.src = imgURL;
    img.onload = function(){
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(img,x,y);
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fillText("Copy : " + count,canvas.width / 2,count * 20);
        if(count === 100){
           ctx.fillRect(0,100,canvas.width,1);
        }
    }
}
function iterate(){
    count += 1;
    copy();
    paste(0,0.5);
    if(count < 100){
       setTimeout(iterate,50);
    }
}

iterate();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width = 300 height = 150></canvas>
At end redline is pixel row 100.
```

Seams that Jpeg compression is much better at preserving the original src image pixels than I suspected. But that does not help solve the problem.

---

### Device specific

So is it a quirk of the device. I look up the specs and nothing stands out. I begin to suspect that you may have a canvas display scaling issues (the canvas resolution not matching the display size)

I start to set up the snippet to use differing resolutions and by shear chance I run the code at the same resolution as the samsung device mentioned in the question.

Blurring yay... but i did not change the canvas pixel scaling, all I did was change the canvas resolution.

#### Example of blurring.

> Note that offset is 0.01 pixels (100th of a pixel)

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "64px Arial";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
ctx.fillText("testing",canvas.width / 2,canvas.height / 2);
ctx.font = "18px Arial";
var count = 0;
var imgURL;
function copy(){
    imgURL = canvas.toDataURL();
}
function paste(x,y){
    var img = new Image;
    img.src = imgURL;
    img.onload = function(){
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(img,x,y);
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fillText("Copy : " + count,canvas.width / 2,count * 20);
    }
}
function iterate(){
    count += 1;
    copy();
    paste(0,0.01);
    if(count < 100){
       setTimeout(iterate,50);
    }
}

iterate();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width = 300 height = 1023></canvas>
```

### Possible fix.

As there is not enough code to give a complete answer the above experiments have given me enough information to make an educated guess.

The problem is specific to the resolution 1024 height. (I have tried a few other (very limited) resolutions and could not get blurring)

The blurring does not occur at that resolution if the image is rendered at the pixel boundaries.

The possible fix.

When you render the image convert the render coordinates to integers using `Math.floor(coordinate)` this will ensure there is no fractional offset, even very tiny offsets that should not affect the image can be amplified by the jpeg compression when the resolution is at 1024 (and maybe some other resolutions as well).

```
var oldImage = new Image;
oldImage.src = "old image url";
oldImage.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(oldImage,Math.floor(x),Math.floor(y));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please check the jsfiddle, sample code is already attached there

Comment: @SarinJacobSunny your fiddle does not work, When I prevent the error and just have the image copy itself it does not blur the text.

Comment: Yes, this issue is not happening across devices.

This happens only in few models of tablets, unfortunately the ones which I am using in production.

I have already mentioned that in the bug :-(

Comment: @SarinJacobSunny Have you tried flooring the render coordinates when you render the image. Any rendering that is not pixel perfect will create blurring for some resolutions

Comment: Flooring is mainly used for avoiding fractional numbers, I debugged and verified that already. I also tried flooring.

Comment: @SarinJacobSunny Somewhere you MUST be adding a fractional component to the rendering position. either directly via the render coordinates or indirectly via a transform (ctx.scale, ctx.translate. ctx.setTransform, or ctx.transform). You can force nearest neighbour rendering (ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false), that will stop the blurring but until you find the offset you will still get a different type of artifact.

Answer (score 1):

I am probably not experienced enough to tell you what about that tablet version, or what in your HTML/Javascript could be causing this issue. I am, however, good at problem solving, and solving puzzles.

I have two possible guesses:

1. Is there anything in your code, which could lead to a change in the resolution? The only reason that I think this may be part of the cause, is that because the image is being redrawn on a canvas that  is the same size, any change in the image size could cause the image to become slightly pixilated. and repetitive changes in the image size would only exaggerate this change.
2. That is probably not the *sole* cause. I think that there is probably an additional cause because the issue is only present on the one specific tablet version. I am not familiar with that tablet version, but is there anything about its OS or interface that could alter the file when it is saved or redisplayed?

As a side note, it would be nice if you could provide a comparison image, just to see the change.

Hope that this at least points you in the right direction.